how to make a get request that accepts an unknown number of input variables in .Net web api
So I am making a very simple web api in .Net with some data I found. One of the columns in this data is called Crop_Type. This column holds things like 'Corn', 'Wheat', 'Cofee'... It is pretty easy to make a get request function that queries the database for only one crop.
i.e.  what I did:
[HttpGet("Crop_Type/{crop_type}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CCImpactAgricultureItem>>> GetByCrop_Type(string crop_type) {...}

now let's say a user wanted to get all  records where Crop_Type = 'Corn',  Crop_Type = 'Wheat',  and Crop_Type = 'Rice'. I guess the user could just make several API calls and join the returned data. However, I was wondering if there is a way to make another get function that can query for this case without having to make a function that explicitly states that it takes in 3 different variables. Like is there a more general way to make a get function that can take any number of different crop types?

How about just letting the user pass in a single or multiple type value? Crop_Type=Corn or Crop_Type=Corn,Wheat,Rice

There's no standard way to specify an array of values in a URI. Different frameworks use different techniques. In ASP.NET Core, you can use int[] id to parse id=1&id=2&id=3

Am I wrong or you can follow this signature?:
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CCImpactAgricultureItem>>> GetByCrop_Type(string[] crop_types) {...}

taking string[] as parameter.

And what would the route in that HttpGet attribute be?

IMHO: GET /Crop_Type/Corn,Wheat,Soybean and it would need i.e. string.Split() logic in the method
